# What does the formula with no left side mean?

Tags: r, formula

I understand the following formulae (I am working with models):

```
x ~ y (x depends on y)
x ~ . (x depends on all variables)
x ~ . -y (x depends on all variables except y)
```

But I don't understand what the formula,which starts with "~", means.

For example:

```
~ .
~ y
~ . -y
```

Thanks.

Comment: Think of it is "by". For example, in [`facet_wrap`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_wrap.html), you can make facets "by class" using `~ class`.

Comment: The context would matter. Using `~` can just be a shortcut to passing an un-evaluated name/symbol to a function.

Comment: Formulas are language objects with a class of "formula". I think the fact that that object structure definition allows for the possibility of one-sided formula doesn't necessarily have a canonical intended purpose, but people who write R code have found uses for that case in specific circumstances.

Comment: formulas are given meaning by the functions they are passed to and can have a different meaning when passing them to different functinons so to understand the meaning of any specific form you need to specify which function you are passing the formula to.

Comment: Something like that: `training.set <- ore.push(npk[1:18, c("N","P","K")])
scoring.set <- ore.push(npk[19:24, c("N","P","K")])
nmf.mod <- ore.odmNMF(~., training.set, num.features = 3)`